# Allow (some) Markdown in question titles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

Markdown in question titles should be rendered, not ignored. E.g., `` Items disapear when `sort!`'ing a list in Guile `` should render as "Items disapear when `sort!`'ing a list in Guile"

([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425497/items-disapear-when-sorting-a-list-in-guile))

Comment: I'm strongly inclined to think such a title would be edited within the first five minutes of the question's lifespan. Titles have to be easily readable, formatting can be counter-productive to that.

Comment: The highlighting of the function name by of the different font makes it a lot more readable for me.

Comment: Maybe if the feature request was just about allowing code to be marked as code in titles rather than opening the door to all of Markdown, it would fare better. The only markup I've ever wished for in titles was to mark code.

Comment: No form of Markdown will ever be supported in titles. [See here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237128)

Comment: @wilx Would you be open to adding "(some)" to this question's title? I think code snippets would be a win. I'm less sure of emphasis or bolding. I'm _very_ sure we don't need or want to support, e.g. tables, lists, or hyperlinks!

Answer (score 42):

It's very important (IMO) to keep the front page clean and elegant.

I won't like it if I see something like:

[image]

Think about badly formatted titles, that we suffer from it even without allowing formation.

I think that keeping the front page uniform and clear is sexier.

Comment: Argument ad absurdum. You can go overboard with formatting within questions as well. Despite that, it is not an argument against using Markdown in questions. That is why people of sufficient reputation can edit questions.

Comment: @wilx Indeed, we *can* and *will* edit questions like that, but it'll be really waste of time and we won't be able to edit *all* titles, the website won't have a uniform design and will look messy. The front page is very important, it  indicates on the professionalism of a website.

Comment: @Maroun Do you really look at the front page frequently? I gave up on that, and the site search, a long time ago. I might briefly look at a question list when I pick up some new library/language, but that's it. And we could, you know, _edit_ the question title formatting to meet something like a 'site style guide'. I think it would actually be very helpful to see code snippets or module/function/whatever names formatted in question lists. And SO/SE _could_ just support the inline code blocks; no need for text formatting (tho I think emphasis and bold would be fine too) or anything else.

Comment: @KennyEvitt I look at the front page, but not frequently. But it's the landing page of Stack Overflow, so it's the first page that my eyes scan the moment I type "stackoverflow" in the address bar. In my opinion, the front page should be clean and minimal in terms of formatting.

Comment: @Maroun I'd guess _most_ users never go to the home/landing page. They're almost all coming from search results. Do you think the front page should be as clean and minimal as Hacker News? I think formatting inline code blocks would be perfectly 'clean' on a programming site. And the current home/landing page is already FAR from minimal.

Comment: @KennyEvitt It's not only users who come from Google, but I was also talking about us, the active users who visit this site on daily basis. I agree that it is not minimal, but (speaking of myself now) what I look at is the active questions pane, which is clean and not disturbing to look at.

Comment: @Maround That's fair – I gave up on trying to regularly 'help' on the site years and years ago. I mostly only visit when I have a specific question or if I notice an interesting question on the sidebar. I very occasionally look at lists of questions for a tag, e.g. when I'm learning something new. But I think it would be perfectly fine for code snippets and even emphasized (or bolded) text to be rendered/formatted for titles in question lists.

Answer (score -8):

We should support at least inline code snippets in question titles. It's useful, e.g. more precise, to know whether a question is referring to integers as an abstract mathematical concept versus an `Int`, a specific class/module/whatever.

Beyond that, I think it might be perfectly fine to also support *emphasis* and **bold** text too. Yes, of course people *could* 'go overboard' – and of course *some* people will too! But that's a bad overly-general argument! The site is *already* filled with bad formatting (and bad questions, answers, and comments). We shouldn't allow the *possibility*, or even inevitability, of some bad thing happening from giving this site's users additional useful tools.

Consider this supposed example of the 'horrors' of allowing Markdown in question titles, copied from [Maroun's answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285731/173497)

[image]

The first title is terrible as-is. The question should be edited anyways! And while whomever it is is doing that, they can remove the extraneous underlining in the title too.

The second title is also bad. The question should be edited anyways! (Hmmm – I'm noticing a pattern!) Whomever it is that volunteers to edit that question can *also* remove the superfluous emphasis from the title.

The third title seems fine – I'd probably remove the double quotes. Oh, no, wait, maybe we should prohibit users from using double quotes because this question title is using them in an unclear or unnecessary manner! Oh, no, that's ridiculous. *This* user using them 'badly' shouldn't preclude others from using them 'correctly'! (I'd probably remove the bolding on "vs" too.)

The fourth title should be edited so that only "sort" is formatted as code.

The fifth title can also be edited. We don't *need* to support any and all Markdown in question titles, underlining *might* be useful, but it's also ambiguous given that it's almost exclusively used for hyperlinks, particularly when the text is blue (or otherwise not the same color as other similar text on a page). But anyone editing the title would probably also un-capitalize "Using" and remove "(python)" (and tagging the question if it wasn't already).

So, basically all of the example titles should be edited – *even if we never allow Markdown support in titles*.

The reasonable conclusion is clear – users must not be allowed to write their own question titles!

Comment: Your assessment is basically the same [as mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405997/157957), but with the opposite conclusion: most of the time, the bad formatting goes along with a bad title in the first place. What you haven't demonstrated is any _good_ titles which benefit from formatting.

Comment: _users must not be allowed to write their own question titles_ --> what? I don't know if that's serious or not.

Comment: @IMSoP I think I have demonstrated a good title which benefits from formatting – my own. It's kinda hard to point to a concrete example given that there is currently no formatting.

Comment: @10Rep It's a reductio ad absurdum of the idea that users should be denied tools because they could be abused. _All_ tools can be abused.