# Double-quotes ("") conversions in question titles

Tags: feature-request, title

I was just looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13743250/372643): `Meaning of - <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>`.

The double quote characters in the title are automatically converted from straight double quotes (`"`) into opening and closing double quotes (`“` and `”`).

Bizarrely, if you try to edit and move your cursor into the title input box with your keyboard (even without changing anything), the previewed title then shows straight quotes. However, saving the edit has no effect.

While I can understand this sort of conversion for prettiness of the typography in some cases, this is a programming website, and quote conversion should virtually never happen, even in titles.

(This is quite possibly a very similar problem to the one in [this other question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286225/372643). In addition, [using Markdown in titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285727/372643) is currently not an option, so we can't escape this use-case between ``` `` ```.)

Comment: Hitting cancel on the edit left the title with `"` until I hit refresh.

Comment: Titles are not made for programmers, they are made for search engines.

Comment: @HansPassant Not really, titles are made for those who're meant to read them: human users who read them.

Comment: Right, they use a search engine to find it.

Comment: ... or they just read the titles from the questions lists. Either way, they *are* ultimately made for programmers. I'm not sure what this has to do with quote conversions anyway.

Comment: Are you sure they were automatically converted? I very much doubt they were. My guess would be this happened at the user's end

Comment: @Pekka웃 Try to edit and fix it by yourself, you'll see.

Comment: I don't think it was made specifically for Programmers. Stackoverflow is only one of the Stackexchange branches. I'm assuming that titles do this in every single branch. They might be able to change it for Stackoverflow, now that it has been mentioned, but I think that it just wasn't an issue when it was first decided.

Comment: Oh, indeed. That seems weird.

Comment: @PatrickvD Stackoverflow was the first. StackExchange didn't arrive until later.

Comment: Ugh. It behaves that way on meta  too D:

Comment: @Deduplicator [Are double quotes being replaced in titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38098/165773) -> [status-bydesign]

Comment: @gnat Thank you, I wasn't aware of the question on MSE. Nevertheless, on a programming-related site, it's not a feature, it's a bug.

Comment: In my opinion as a programmer, it really doesn't matter much. In the XML example you give the smart quotes don't confuse things, and even if a question is specifically related to quote characters it will, like most good questions, have an appropriately-formatted code example in the question body rather than relying on everything being in the title.

Comment: The title isn't the place for meaningful code fragments - it's the place for a human-readable summary of the question. Any important code should be in the body of the question (even if that means it ends up in both; "see title" is terrible content for any question). So for that reason, I'd agree with the design: human-friendly bits should have human-friendly formatting.

Comment: @Dave I agree this should also be in the body of the question. The problem here is that it's human-friendly formatting that effectively changes the meaning (and it's code meant to be read by humans as it is, not poetry).

Comment: Agreed with the OP. Why does the system want to change what I type for a title? _What is the design?_ (Was it done for the explicit purpose of preventing "See title" remarks?) With regard to search engines: why would “” be found more easily than "" for a search engine? And this messes up searching in the page (Ctrl+F) unless I specifically remember to search for “ rather than ".